# While Debugging Where are the Variables Available to a JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am currently trying to debug through a JSP to find the value of a mystery variable being passed in from an interceptor I cannot attach a source to--and thus I cannot debug through the interceptor.

I read a number of posts saying that it is very difficult to find the variables available to a JSP if you're debugging through it, but unfortunately this might be one of the only ways I can solve my issue.

Does anyone know of any articles that detail the variable structure of a JSP, or more specifically, what object(s) store these values?

As a side note, I am using Eclipse to develop/debug.

Answer (score 1):

with the vague question I can provide some vague answers:

implicit objects:

- response
- request

From those you can derive cookies and session variables. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hmm maybe... For example, say I have a tag like <s:iterator value="somelist">, is there somewhere within the variable stack that I can see the actual value of the variable "somelist"? I think I managed to find the actual tags within the page, but not the values that they are associated with.

Comment: So this is really dependent on your appserver environment. When you have a taglibrary (as it appears you do) - you will also have configuration xml file(s) that dictate what class handles what tag. From there you can then debug and determine what variables, arguments and parameters are necessary to get the desired result from a specific tag.   Regarding specific tags, you'll need to refer to your appserver or webapp API to determine how to properly configure and edit these tag delegations

Answer (score 1):

Is your container a JSR-45 (as far as I remember the JSR number) compatible container? If so you can attach your IDE to it for debugging JSPs, by the way it is somehow hard to find the variables.

Comment: I can place breakpoints in my JSPs with Eclipse, but there are a ton of variables with a ton of depth, so I'm lost as to where I need to look to find the variables accessible in the JSP.